# Relationship between two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables in LibraryDB. One is Book_Master and the other is Languages. I have used langid in Book_Master as a Foreign Key and want to make a relationship between these two tables but I've got an error. Picture is given in the description. Help me Programmers..!! Here is the picture  [Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRmYW.png)

Comment: Is the column nullable? Is there a default value on the column? There may already be data in that column preventing the foreign key check from succeeding

Comment: Yeah this is most likely because there is some data preventing the key to be created. Of course this is mostly guessing because you didn't provide much of anything resembling details about your tables.

Comment: Your Book_Master table already has data in it. So I assume it has a LangID column which is the foreign key to the Languages table. That column needs to be nullable AND any data in the LangID column needs to exist in the Languages table already.

Comment: Both the columns are nullable.... I haven't put any data yet in both the tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyze your tables.

```
select b.LangID
from book_master b
left join Languages L on b.LangID = L.LangID
where L.LangID is null
```

The result is LangID's in Book_master which don't exist in Languages (and block FK creation).

Comment: The langid in Book_Master is 0

Comment: Set these values in `book_master` to existing values or to `null` to create FK

Comment: Thank you So Much Sir... I did unchecked the checkbox of langid in Book_Master which was a foriegn key ..but when i checked it and update the langid to NULL.. Then relationship creates.... Bundle of thanks